# Issues with an external reference between two spreadsheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using Excel 365 and attempting to use the =INDIRECT formula to reference data in another spreadsheet, but I continue to get #Blocked! and #REF! errors.  Adding an absolute reference works and will cause the Indirect references to function properly.

**Setup**
A worksheet is created through automation with reporting for specific customers KPIs (source worksheet) and saved to a shared folder.  Users have a worksheet with indirect references to organize the data and make ready for a customer facing presentation (template worksheet).  As far as I can tell, permissions are set to allow anyone within the org to edit either of the docs.

**Goal**
The goal is to have multiple references on the page to centralize data from the referenced worksheet.  An indirect reference is being used so that the user can update the file location within their template to a different file location for another customer and the data is updated accordingly.

**Results**
I receive a Blocked error when I add the formula, but if make an absolute reference to the data elsewhere on the page, the indirect reference will update with the correct output.  If I add another formula on the page for a different data set, the output is " 0 ".  If an absolute reference with the latter request is made elsewhere on the page, the indirect reference will update to the correct information.

This looks to be a larger issue beyond the formula.  Does anyone have any other suggestions or feedback on how I can get this to work?

Comment: `#BLOCKED!` error shows up when the required resource can't be accessed, per `MS` Documentations **[here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-to-correct-a-blocked-error-13be117b-92e4-400a-a215-aa59d37d6e7c)** and there are some reasons sighted take a look on it